# How to publish the web application in Symbian store?

Tags: javascript, symbian, nokia, symbian3

I have developed symbian web application using Nokia web developer environment. now i would like to know how to publish my web application to symbian store. still i am searching i didn't get the answer. please help me to publish my application.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Nokia Store is closing down, your choice of store would then be the [Opera Store](http://apps.opera.com/en_us/), so check out what option would they have, if any, for Symbian Web runtime apps.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. i got solution from your response.

Answer (score 0):

Check here: http://applist.schumi1331.de/

It has a real store application with update support :)